# Child of the Moon not making a skill a class skill?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, traits

So, looking at most traits, any trait they give a bonus to tends to make it a class skill, yet Child of the Moon, at least in the description provided by D20PFSRD, does not have it do so (it does say choose Climb, Stealth or Swim).

I'm just curious if this is true in the main book, or it's just something that they overlooked, or what?  My DM is considering just house-ruling it to grant the class skill, but I figured I'd ask here.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there are tons of traits that grant bonuses and not make them class-skills. And I know because that has frustrated me in the past. To list a few:

[Eye for the Plunder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/campaign-traits/skull-shackles/eye-for-plunder),
[Pioneer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/campaign-traits/kingmaker/pioneer),
[Ruin Raider](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/campaign-traits/shattered-star/ruin-raider),
[Spirit Sense](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/faith-traits/spirit-sense),
[Ghost Sight](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/ghost-sight),
[Aerial Observer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/aerial-observer-sylph),
[Big Ears](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/big-ears),
[Blood of Dragons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/blood-of-dragons),
[Born in the Light](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/born-in-the-light---dhampir),
[Goldsniffer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/goldsniffer),
[Old Before Your Time](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/old-before-your-time-dhampir---ancient-born),
[Pearl Diver](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/pearl-diver-half-elf),
[Scrapper](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/scrapper),
[Seeker of Brightness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/seeker-of-brightness),
[Wind-Carried Voice](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/wind-carried-voices-sylph),
[Coincunning](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/regional-traits/coincunning-janderhoff),
[Deepsea Native](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/regional-traits/deepsea-native),
[Frontier-Forged](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/regional-traits/frontier-forged),
[Garbage Picker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/regional-traits/dump-salvager),
[Ghoulish Affinity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/regional-traits/ghoulish-affinity),
[Pure Legion Recruit](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/regional-traits/pure-legion-recruit),
[Region Recluse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/regional-traits/regional-recluse-varisia),
[Eyes of the Wild](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/religion-traits/eyes-of-the-wild),
[Opener of Doors](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/religion-traits/opener-of-doors),
[Sense of Order](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/religion-traits/sense-of-order)...

Yes, that's a lot. And those are only traits that grant bonuses to **Perception**. Yes, some of them also grant another benefit on top of the perception bonus, others will grant the bonus only in specific situations. But none of those will make Perception a class-skill to your character.

[Child of the Moon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/child-of-the-moon-magic/) is no exception here, specially considering that it can grant up to +4 on your skill checks under very specific conditions. Overall, it's not a bad trait, but it's not great either.

Traits that grant skills as class-skills usually do little other than grant a +1 bonus to that skill. Sometimes you are granted the bonus to two skills and has to pick one of them to become a class skill. But that's not a rule set in stone either, as campaign specific traits have been proved to be as strong as two traits or a single feat.

Answer (score 2):

D20PFSRD is correct on the wording and mechanics of Child of the Moon.

Child of the Moon replaces the usual benefit of getting the selected skill as a class skill with its own moon-related bonuses. It does stack with the class skill bonus if the skill is already on your class list or is added some other way.